# Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/me/.yarnrc'

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm getting this message when trying to install a react app. Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/me/.yarnrc'

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

The message is related to your package manager rather than with react.
I don't use myself Yarn but in your case it appears that yarn cannot access the ~/.yarnrc file.

To solve this problem you have to give the file the correct permissions.

This may help:

```
sudo chown $USER ~/.yarnrc
sudo chmod +r ~/.yarnrc
```